# Fix Dartz package with non nullable

Tags: flutter, dart, dartz

I moved my project to the sdk 2.12 and trying to update my code with the non-nullable crap.

Now I don't understand how to fix things in Dartz package...

Example:

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:mobile_100asa/http.dart';

class StatusApi {
  String endpoint = 'https://myApi.net';

  Future<Either<Exception, String>?> getStatus() async { // Forced to make nullable response here
    try {
      var response = await dio.get('$endpoint/test');
      return Right(response);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return (Left(error)); // Error Here
    }
  }
}
```

I'm forced to make a nullable response and then I don't know what is wrong with the `catch(error)`.

It says: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Exception*'.

How this should be fixed?

Comment: I strongly suggest the fpdart package instead of dartz.  fpdart has active development, and is far better documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `dartz: ^0.10.0-nullsafety.2`, which is the pre-release version for null safety. Please check for the latest version on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz).

Comment: not aware about that... I will it a try! Thanks!